# How to recalculate the normals (or just solve this problem) for the edges of my hand model?

Tags: modeling

So I am making a humanoid body in Blender, and everything else about it looks fine, except this one loop on the hand that I have been working at for around 2 hours, and cannot seem to fix, despite remodeling the entire hand. It looks like I just need to recalculate the normals, but you can only apply that to faces to my knowledge, so that may not be the solution. I tried to shade flat, but that leaves me with the same edge loop looking very rigid and not curved like I want it, even though I have a subdivision surface in place. so I actually have two questions then:

A) how do you recalculate normals on an edge?
B) how do you make edge loops smooth without compromising the geometry of the rest of the model?

the image attached[image] shows what it looks like when shaded smooth ,and shaded flat looks just like this, but the faulty loop has no curvature.

I should also point out I am very, very new to this and this is the first model I have ever made, so forgive my ignorance to some of the more technical terms.

hope one of you can help me :)

here is the file @John Eason
[image]

Comment: Can you share your Blend file (of just the hand if possible to keep the size down). https://blend-exchange.com/help

Answer (score 4):

The normals of the four fingers are inverted as shown in red below. Click the  <kbd>Show</kbd><kbd>Overlays</kbd> dropdown in the top toolbar and check <kbd>Face</kbd><kbd>Orientation</kbd> to show the problem. (You can drag the tollbar left and right with the middle mouse button to make the overlay icon visible if the screen is too narrow.)

[image]

Then go into <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode, select <kbd>All</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals.

[image]

Comment: wow, thanks! this has got to be the first time I have ever got an answer that was both simple and helpful out of a support forum that actually works.

Comment: No problem! Nice simple solution in this case! Please check the tick to the left of my answer to accept it.